# Gnome 3 gdm fails to start after preupgrade from fedora 14 to 15

Tags: gdm, gnome-shell

I'm not able to boot fedora 15 in runlevel 5. After all services start, when the login screen should appear, gdm just show a mouse waiting cursor and keeps restarting itself.

From /var/log/gdm/:0-greeter.log

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
/usr/bin/gnome-session: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/modules/libatk-bridge.so: undefined symbol: atk_plug_get_type
/usr/libexec/gnome-setting-daemon: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gtk-3.0modules/libatk-bridge.so: undefined symbol: atk_plug_get_type
```

Where should atk_plug_get_type be defined?

Edit: Here a better description of the error

```
(system-config-network-gui:2643): Gnome-WARNING **: Accessibility: failed to find module 'libgail-gnome' which is needed to make this application accessible
/usr/bin/python: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libatk-bridge.so: undefined symbol: atk_plug_get_type
```

Why there are still references to gtk2? Did preupgrade fail? Attaching upgrade log... it seems gdm was not added, but it is present in the users and groups list.

```
May 26 11:25:52 sysimage sendmail[1076]: alias database /etc/aliases rebuilt by root
May 26 11:25:52 sysimage sendmail[1076]: /etc/aliases: 77 aliases, longest 23 bytes, 795 bytes total
May 26 11:46:09 sysimage useradd[1793]: failed adding user 'dbus', data deleted
May 26 11:53:37 sysimage systemd-machine-id-setup[2443]: Initializing machine ID from D-Bus machine ID.
May 26 11:55:28 sysimage useradd[2835]: failed adding user 'apache', data deleted
May 26 11:55:38 sysimage useradd[2842]: failed adding user 'haldaemon', data deleted
May 26 11:55:43 sysimage useradd[2848]: failed adding user 'smolt', data deleted
May 26 11:57:32 sysimage sendmail[3032]: alias database /etc/aliases rebuilt by root
May 26 11:57:32 sysimage sendmail[3032]: /etc/aliases: 77 aliases, longest 23 bytes, 795 bytes total
May 26 11:57:46 sysimage groupadd[3066]: group added to /etc/group: name=cgred, GID=482
May 26 11:57:47 sysimage groupadd[3066]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=cgred
May 26 11:57:47 sysimage groupadd[3066]: new group: name=cgred, GID=482
May 26 11:58:42 sysimage useradd[3086]: failed adding user 'ntp', data deleted
May 26 12:00:13 sysimage dbus: avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=2)
May 26 12:15:08 sysimage useradd[4950]: failed adding user 'gdm', data deleted
May 26 12:24:39 sysimage dbus: avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=3)
May 26 12:25:24 sysimage useradd[5522]: failed adding user 'mysql', data deleted
May 26 12:25:37 sysimage useradd[5533]: failed adding user 'rpcuser', data deleted
May 26 12:26:31 sysimage useradd[5592]: failed adding user 'tcpdump', data deleted
```

Any suggestions before I revert installation to F14?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `ldd` to see whether you're missing any libraries needed by libatk-bridge:

```
ldd /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/modules/libatk-bridge.so
```

Comment: no libraries listed by this command are missing

Comment: Chances are one of those dynamically linked libraries is the wrong version.

Comment: By chanche system-config-network-gui throwed the error I report in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you can get at a console and have Internet access, try running the following commands to fix any missing/broken packages.  The first one will make sure everything's up to date while the second will force reinstall the package that provides `libatk-bridge.so`.

```
su -c 'yum distro-sync'
su -c 'yum reinstall at-spi2-atk'
```

I looked around a little more and other people were experiencing at the least the first error in your log output due to SELinux.  Try relabeling your filesystem by running the following command as `root` and rebooting:

```
touch /.autorelabel
```

If that doesn't fix the problem try switching SELinux to permissive mode by editing `/etc/selinux/config` and changing the line starting with `SELINUX=` to:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

If that corrects your problem, run `setroubleshoot` and file a bug with Fedora so they can fix the problem.

Comment: distro-sync installed some updates, but the problem persist even after reinstalling at-spi2-atk

Comment: @digital:  I did a little digging around and several people experienced the first error in your log as a result of some SELinux wonkiness.  See my updated answer for some more troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion but with no luck. It seems a much deeper problem is present

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you accidentally corrupt your /etc/passwd file or the /etc/passwd- shadow file?
2. X11 always throws me for a loop on upgrades. Try renaming /etc/X11/xorg.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.fc14 and reboot. It's quite possible you've forgotten to reinstall kernel drivers for your video card or it just needs a little shove.
3. Set your /etc/inittab to runlevel 3 and reboot. yum update and then restart. It might have missed something or you may not have rebooted when necessary.
4. Do a yum grouplist to check out the groups available to you and groupinstall the ones relevant to gnome 3. I imagine it's probably "Desktop" and a few others.

All are guesses without knowing the full order of operations. Hope this helps.